# Origins of zzzzz (indicating sleep)

Tags: etymology

It is common to use zzzzz (or some other number of z letters) to indicate that the "speaker" is asleep. What is the origin of such a usage?

Comment: Let me just catch some zzzz... what *is* the plural, since the letter **Z** in Britian is **zed** and not **zee**?